# Open separate page as modal pop up in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-router

I use angular-ui-router and angular-bootstrap in my project.

I want to implement follow use case:

When user click on icon in ng-grid, I want to open separate page as a modal pop up
Also I want to pass value from one page to another modal pop up

Following code is not working for me.Is there any way to open separate page as modal pop up in angular.js

on this anchor click i am trying to open modal pop up

```
<a href="" ng-click="plCtrl.openPopupScreen()"><i class="pledit"></i></a>
```

Code to open modal pop up

```
self.openPopupScreen = function () {
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'test.html',
            windowClass: 'app-modal-window',
            controller: 'childController',
            backdrop: 'static'
           })
```

Modal pop up UI

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="empContoller as emCtrl" ng-cloak>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <form role="form" name="empForm" novalidate ng-show="empCtrl.initialized">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="empnmae">Name</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="Note" placeholder="Enter name" min="0" maxlength="5000" rows="10" ng-model="emCtrl.Note"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what is not working. The $modal service in angular-bootstrap works the way you want. Check for any error messages in JS console. - I recommend you start from sample in this page: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: above code works if modal pop up is on same page only.It is not working if i want to open separate page as a modal pop up.

Comment: You mean it works if you remove the `templateUrl` attribute and put the HTML in the same page? Try specifying an absolute URL. Also, again, please check the JS console. Most of the times the error messages are very helpful.